# Pandas groupby output

Tags: python, pandas

I have grouped data by "release_year"

`df_cleaning_melted[['release_year', 'genre']].groupby('release_year').genre.value_counts()`

output was like that in attached screenshot:
[output screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmYhN.png)

I want to find the maximum value of every group?

When I add .max() at the end of the above code line it returns only single value.

Comment: You mean you want to find max for (release_year,genre)? or only release_year

Comment: Every year has multiple genres of movies for example counts of movies genre for one year 1960 are (drama 6, comedy 5, action 10). I want to find the genre which has maximum count with the name of this genre every year.

Answer (score 0):

Use `max` with level:

```
(df_cleaning_melted[['release_year', 'genre']]
    .groupby('release_year').genre.value_counts()
    .max(level='release_year')
)
```

Comment: The code worked well, it displayed the maximum number of value_counts every year successfully, How I could display the name of such genre (with max count)?